# xml to json array for sql

Tags: php, sql, json, xml

I need to import a file to my database. I get the file from a url with curl, but I can't import it. I guess I am pretty close, but I am missing out on something with my foreach loop to get all the advertiser. I get an array, but not the elements I need

```
public function import()
{
    $url = $this->get_data();

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url);
    $json_string = json_encode($xml);    
    $advertisers = json_decode($json_string, TRUE);
    $this->import_advertiser($advertisers);
}

public function import_advertiser($advertisers = [])
{
    echo $advertisers;
    if($advertisers) {
    foreach($advertisers as $advertiser)
    {   
    $attr = [
        'advertiser-id'       => $advertiser->advertiser-id,
        'advertiser-name'     => $advertiser->advertiser-name,
        'program-url'         => $advertiser->program-url,
        'relationship-status' => $advertiser->relationship-status,
        ];
    $this->db->replace($this->table_program_name, $attr);
    }
}}
```

My xml looks like this, Edited:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cj-api>
  <advertisers total-matched="2" records-returned="2" page-number="1">
    <advertiser>
      <advertiser-id>4942550</advertiser-id>
      <account-status>Active</account-status>
      <seven-day-epc>26.63</seven-day-epc>
      <three-month-epc>28.71</three-month-epc>
      <language>en</language>
      <advertiser-name>NIKE</advertiser-name>
      <program-url>http://www.nike.com</program-url>
      <relationship-status>notjoined</relationship-status>
      <mobile-tracking-certified>true</mobile-tracking-certified>
      <cookieless-tracking-enabled>true</cookieless-tracking-enabled>
      <network-rank>5</network-rank>
      <primary-category>
        <parent>Sports &amp; Fitness</parent>
        <child>Apparel</child>
      </primary-category>
      <performance-incentives>false</performance-incentives>
      <actions>
        <action>
          <name>Nike.com Purchase</name>
          <type>advanced sale</type>
          <id>393783</id>
          <commission>
            <itemlist name="Hurley Non-Commissionables" id="33329">USD 0.00</itemlist>
            <itemlist name="Converse Non-Commissionables" id="33330">USD 0.00</itemlist>
            <itemlist name="Nike Non-Commissionables" id="33331">USD 0.00</itemlist>
            <itemlist name="Flash Sale" id="33643">1.00%</itemlist>
            <itemlist name="Flash Sale Non-Commissionables" id="33644">USD 0.00</itemlist>
            <default>3.00%</default>
          </commission>
        </action>
        <action>
          <name>Nike.com Mobile Purchase</name>
          <type>advanced sale</type>
          <id>393784</id>
          <commission>
            <itemlist name="Hurley Non-Commissionables" id="33329">USD 0.00</itemlist>
            <itemlist name="Converse Non-Commissionables" id="33330">USD 0.00</itemlist>
            <itemlist name="Nike Non-Commissionables" id="33331">USD 0.00</itemlist>
            <itemlist name="Flash Sale" id="33643">1.00%</itemlist>
            <itemlist name="Flash Sale Non-Commissionables" id="33644">USD 0.00</itemlist>
            <default>3.00%</default>
          </commission>
        </action>
      </actions>
      <link-types>
        <link-type>Text Link</link-type>
        <link-type>Banner</link-type>
        <link-type>OtherDeepLink</link-type>
        <link-type>Test Link</link-type>
        <link-type>DeepLink</link-type>
        <link-type>AutoMoneyDeepLink</link-type>
      </link-types>
    </advertiser>
    <advertiser>
      <advertiser-id>4659293</advertiser-id>
      <account-status>Setup</account-status>
      <seven-day-epc>N/A</seven-day-epc>
      <three-month-epc>N/A</three-month-epc>
      <language>en</language>
      <advertiser-name>Nike</advertiser-name>
      <program-url>http://www.nike.com</program-url>
      <relationship-status>notjoined</relationship-status>
      <mobile-tracking-certified>false</mobile-tracking-certified>
      <cookieless-tracking-enabled>false</cookieless-tracking-enabled>
      <network-rank>0</network-rank>
      <primary-category>
        <parent>Sports &amp; Fitness</parent>
        <child>Apparel</child>
      </primary-category>
      <performance-incentives/>
      <actions/>
      <link-types>
        <link-type>Text Link</link-type>
      </link-types>
    </advertiser>
  </advertisers>
</cj-api>
```

I see that it tried to connect to my database, but the table is not importing the data

Comment: I get an error reported by `$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url);` from this element in the XML file `<parent>Home & Garden</parent>`

Comment: I am sry, I edited my xml now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have got arrays and objects a little confused in this function

As you used `$advertisers = json_decode($json_string, TRUE);` in the previous function then a couple of simple changes will fix the creation of the `$attr` array. Plus you were not starting your foreach loop at the right point in the data structure.

```
function import_advertiser($advertisers = [])
{

    if($advertisers) {
        foreach($advertisers['advertisers']['advertiser'] as $advertiser) {   
            $attr = [
                'advertiser-id'       => $advertiser['advertiser-id'],
                'advertiser-name'     => $advertiser['advertiser-name'],
                'program-url'         => $advertiser['program-url'],
                'relationship-status' => $advertiser['relationship-status']
                ];
            $this->db->replace($this->table_program_name, $attr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this also, but forgot to use $advertisers['advertisers']['advertiser'], thank you very much, this solved my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is not well formed. The "&" should be

- either escaped (`<parent>Home &amp; Garden</parent>`)
- or placed into a CDATA section (`<parent><![CDATA[Home & Garden]]></parent>`)